# How do I make XamCurrencyEditor accept either parentheses or a minus sign?

Tags: wpf, infragistics

```
<XamCurrencyEditor FormatProvider="{Binding Path=CurrencyFormat.CurrencyFormatInfo}"
                   Mask="{Binding Path=CalculatedMask}" />
```

`CurrencyFormat.CurrencyFormatInfo` is a [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) calculated from our currency format business object.  `CalculatedMask` is set to "{currency:-22.2:c}", which allows positive or negative currencies with up to 22 digits before the decimal and 2 after.

I would like the editor to allow either parenthesis or a minus sign for negative values:

- $ -123.45
- ($ 123.45)

[CurrencyNegativePattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx) is already set to 0.  I tried changing the Mask to "{currency:(22.2):c}", but that is just inserted as a literal string.  Will I have to generate a [custom format string](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/28118.aspx) to get the desired behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure you can accomplish this without a custom format string or regex of some sort. The CurrencyNegativePattern sort of forces you to choose one or the other. Why do you want both? Having both can be confusing and might look sloppy. If you are trying to cater to different audiences you could have a setting in your application that would change the CurrencyNegativePattern to the desired format.

Comment: @Danielle I'm having trouble getting XamCurrencyEditor to allow parentheses at all, even when CurrencyNegativePattern is 0.

Answer (score 0):

As a partial solution, adding `Format="C"` causes the editor to fully respect the `FormatProvider` when formatting its value.

```
<XamCurrencyEditor FormatProvider="{Binding Path=CurrencyFormat.CurrencyFormatInfo}"
                   Mask="{Binding Path=CalculatedMask}"
                   Format="C" />
```

The editor still refuses to accept parentheses.  If anyone from Infragistics is reading, please consider this a feature request.

Comment: From my experience, infragistics support is very good. but I don't think they will also search for new feature requests on web :)